# Filtering ROOT path with Restlet and GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, restlet

I have this code that I need to be able to trigger the MyFilter when `ROOT_URI` is accessed:

```
private static final String ROOT_URI = "/";
private static final String ROOT_REST_URI = "/rest/";

@Override
public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Guice.createInjector(new GuiceConfigModule(this.getContext()),
            new SelfInjectingServerResourceModule());

    Router router = new Router(getContext());

    router.attach(ROOT_URI + "{id}", new GaeRedirector(getContext(), "{id}"));
    router.attach(ROOT_REST_URI, GaeRootServerResource.class);

    MyFilter mFilter = new MyFilter(getContext());
    MyFilter.setNext(router);

    return mFilter;
}
```

The MyFilter is only triggered when ROOT_REST_URI is accessed. Restlet team already advised through mail group that I need to put a routing into the ROOT_URI first.

The question is,

- the `ROOT_URI` is not in the routing because in the web.xml, a `welcome-file` setting is there pointing to index.html. So when `http://localhost:8080/` is accessed it returns the *index.html* page.

I have also tried adding (as a routing to ROOT_URI to make MyFilter work on ROOT_URI):

```
Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(), "war:///doc");
router.attach(ROOT_URI, directory);
```

Yet, this Directory routing would not work with GAE. It seems it does not trigger at all. accessing the `http://localhost:8080/` with this Directory code in place, still the index.html is shown and no `MyFilter` is triggered.

Now if I remove the `<welcome-file>` in web.xml. The MyFilter gets triggered but the `index.html` cannot be shown now. Unless explicitly through adding `/index.html` to the request.

**What solution there may be for this scenario?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to set the default index name for the directory as follow:

```
Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(), "war:///doc");
directory.setIndexName("index.html");
```

Comment: Thierry, an issue is filed for this bug: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-framework-java/issues/1024

Comment: Hi, I've added a comment in the github issue. I hope this will help you.